# Import a legacy Mycelium wallet from my old phone but see no transactions

Tags: wallet-recovery, private-key-export, import, mycelium-wallet

I am moving a Mycelium wallet from my old to my new phone, Android to Android.
I have an HD wallet and I have several legacy wallets.

Unfortunately, Mycelium doesn't have an easy way to copy all wallets and transaction labels from one phone to another so I do this manually.

Some of the legacy wallets I import, import fine but they do not show any transactions in the transactions tab. They do have transactions according to the old phone and block explorers on the net.

Why does this happen? How can I solve it?

Comment: Typically happens for importing public keys (readonly)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
It is a bug in mycelium... When you show the qr code of a legacy wallet in the "balance" tab, you can click on the qr code to change the format of the bitcoin address... P2PKH or Bech32.... Etc...

It turns out that mycelium will only show the transactions in the imported wallet only if you import Legacy(P2PKH) qr codes!
It took me hours to figure this one out hope i helped!

Comment: Sometimes this solution only shows some transactions but not all, then the solution is to import the private key and not the public one

Comment: If you want to be able to spend from the new wallet, you should definitely import all the private keys. The public keys will only allow you to watch, but not to spend.